# Advertising SR with "Community Promotion Ads - 2016"

Tags: discussion, advertising

This post is for our advertisements on **other** SE sites. Promoting our site is a great way to spread the word about SR.

If you have an advertisement running on another site, please include the site's name and a link to the advertisement.

For each ad, even if you think a better ad could be made, please first **upvote it** so that it reaches the required threshold of 6 votes to get displayed, thanks!

The image itself can still be modified, so please comment/answer your ideas/designs/images.

Comment: Sorry for the repetition of the images, the editor made me add more substance than just a link and I didn't want to write an essay for each post :-)

Comment: Why on earth isn't there one for plain old SO?  I continue to see many questions slammed closed with no mention of SR to OP.

Comment: @IraBaxter SO doesn't have the same ads that SU, SF and graduated SE2.0 sites get. On SO, community ads are restricted to open source projects seeking contributors.

Comment: @Gilles:  Ah.   A shame.   Seems like a lot of indirect resistance at SO to connecting people to SR; even the "don't ask for a resource" close reason doesn't hint that SR exists.

Comment: @Gilles... uh, on second thought, isn't SR an "open source" project to build a great website about recommendations?  And aren't we seeking contributors?  Half-serious thought.

Answer (score 2):

## WordPress Development

### [Software Recommendations advertisement on WordPress Development](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4121/42899)

[image: Visit Software Recommendations to find plugins that meet your every need]

*I created this but feel free to tell me to go with Undo's if you don't like it:)*

Comment: This is a good ad: it makes sense, and it's tailored to its audience.

Answer (score 1):

## Drupal Answers

### [Software Recommendations advertisement on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3440/59223)

[image: Software Recommendations SE]